# Akka actoreRef with macWire DI, actoreRef is not set

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-http, macwire

I have a 2 actors, `Actor1` and `Actor2`. `Actor1` wants to send `MyMsg1` to `Actor2`, and `Actor2` after doing some work and getting `Future[MyMsg2]` wants to send `MyMsg2` to `Actor1`. I have got this working one way but it fails with DI.

1. Scenario 1 - Working scenario

   - Actor1 -->MyMsg1-->Actor2
   - Actor2 MyMsgHandler - Processes message(with Future), does pipeTo to sender with `MyMsg2`. Works fine, Actor1 recvs `MyMsg2`
2. Scenario2 - Failing scenario

   - Actor1 has a bean injected via MacWire  - `myBean`.
   - `myBean` has `Actor2` injected as a bean and  sends `MyMsg1` to Actor2
   - Actor2 MyMsgHandler processes message(with Future), does pipeTo to sender and tries sending `MyMsg2` - Goes to deadLetter. The actor Ref for sender is never set.

How do I fix this?

Pasting code also

```
class Actor1(failedService: FailedService, actor2: ActorRef @@ Actor2) extends Actor{
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case TriggerActor1() =>
      println("Actor1 triggered from REST controller. Send msg to actor 2")
      failedService.testSend()
      //actor2 ! Msg1()
    case Msg2() => println("got msg2 from actor 1")
  }

class Actor2 extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Msg1() => {
      println("send without future")
      val origsender = sender()
      origsender ! Msg2()
    }
  }

class FailedService(actor2: ActorRef@@Actor2) {
  def testSend() = {
    actor2 ! Msg1()
  }
}
```

With my current code as shared above, `Actor1` is able to send `Msg1` to `Actor2`
and `actor2` responds with `Msg2` but `Msg2` goes to deadletter. I get the below error
`akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef - Message [backup.failedakka.Msg2] from Actor[akka://application/user/actor2#-662746578] to Actor[akka://application/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered.`

However, if insted of using the line `failedService.testSend()` in my Actor1, I uncomment the line below it
and use that to communicate, things work fine.
Is the Q clear now? I am injecting dependencies with MacWire

Comment: can you add your codes ? ill try to help.

Comment: @HuntsMan, I have pasted the code also

Comment: Hello i think because your using the   FailedService  as a gateway which is not an actor and when the actor2 send Msg2 to the sender the sender which is FailedService and  currently terminated and  which is already dead. and. you can contact directly to the Actor1 to Actor2 btw FailedService is not an actor.

Answer (score 1):

`!` is defined as:

```
def !(message: Any)(implicit sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Unit
```

You can see the problem now, there's no implicit sender in scope of `FailedService`, although it is in scope "inside" an actor implementation.

I think you want to do:

```
class FailedService(actor2: ActorRef@@Actor2) {
  def testSend(implicit sender: ActorRef) = {
    actor2 ! Msg1()
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. Looks like it works. I will test a bit more and tick mark the answer. Can you help me understand a bit more how the sender got passed? I know that using implicit, let us say if i say ``implicit val a = 10``, that is a default int available, or I can provide implicit serializer, etc. But I am a bit confused about currying and how implicit is helping here passing the ref. Any more explanation?

Comment: Sorry, this place is too small for detailed explanations... let me link a [documentation page](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html) that should help.

Comment: Basically inside the actor class you have an implicit `ActorRef` defined (by a base class), which gets passed to `!` "implicitly" :). In the `testSend` method you do not have that implicit in scope; an implicit parameter declares 2 things in reality: an incoming parameter should be searched by scalac at the call-site scope and that inside the function the value is treated as an implicit value (hence scalac will find it and pass it in functions automatically).